# Firefox: How to recover deleted bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks

When organizing the bookmarks in my Firefox browser I had a folder highlighted and hit `Delete` by mistake. How can I recover the folder?

NOTE: It's too late to hit `Control + Z`, and the bookmarked sites aren't in my history anymore.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1009770

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples Post the content of that support answer along with a link to the page, and I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

From [this discussion](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1009770) on the Firefox forums:

> [...] you can restore the bookmarks from a JSON backup in the bookmarkbackups folder.
>
> - Bookmarks > Show All Bookmarks > Import & Backup > Restore
>
> This will replace all current bookmarks and you lose bookmarks that were added since that backup was created.
> See:
>
> - https://kb.mozillazine.org/Backing_up_and_restoring_bookmarks_-_Firefox
>
> In that case, you need to export the current bookmarks to an HTML file before doing the restore and import that HTML file after you have restored the JSON backup.
>
> - Bookmark Deduplicator: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/bookmark-deduplicator/

Comment: Backups of your bookmarks can be found in this location: `%AppData%\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile name>\bookmarkbackups`. Go to Bookmarks > Show All Bookmarks > Import & Backup > Restore > Choose file > browse to the above location & select to restore